# Manipulate DOM on another page in Datatables

Tags: datatables

How can I manipulate DOM on page 2 (e.g. TD) when you are in page 1 of Datatables?

Using this code isn't possible because TD of another page is not on DOM until you select page 2.

```
$("td").html("some code here..");
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Or do?

Comment: @davidkonrad i want to uncheck all checkboxes (checkboxes aren't bound to data source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jQuery DataTables, you cannot access the DOM on a different screen, because DOM elements exist on the current screen only.

Instead, you can access or change the DataTable's internal value of a table cell's contents by using the [**`cell().data()`**](http://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()) function:

```
myDataTable.cell(row,column).data('some code here ...');
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33eL9msq/)**